# Go Lang exec/spawn a ssh session

Tags: ssh, go, fork, lang

I'm trying to work out the mechanism to fork/start a ssh terminal session
i.e I want to be logged into remote server (my keys are on server) if I execute this program.

Right now it just executes but nothing happens.

```
package main

import (
 "os/exec"   
 "os"
)

func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("ssh","root@SERVER-IP")
  cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
  //cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
  cmd.Run()

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmd.Run` waits for the command to complete. Your ssh session should (normally) not exit without user interaction. Therefore your program blocks, since it waits for the `ssh` process to finish.

You may want to either

- also redirect Stdin, so you can interact with the ssh session
- execute `ssh me@server somecommand`. In the last form a specific command gets executed and the output of this command gets redirected.
- take a look at the [ssh package](https://golang.org/pkg/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)

Comment: I should add that one have to also process `stderr` of the session as the command run in it might legitimately fail, and whatever it dumps to its `stderr` should be somehow processed by the local controlling program.

Answer (score -2):

I've done library that can cover your requiremenets: https://github.com/shagabutdinov/shell; checkout if it helps or not.

You can use this library to start ssh session and execute the commands:

```
key, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey([]byte(YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY))
if(err != nil) {
     panic(err)
}

shell, err = shell.NewRemote(shell.RemoteConfig{
    Host: "root@example.com:22",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(key)},
})

if(err != nil) {
    panic(err)
}

shell.Run("cat /etc/hostname", func(_ int, message string) {
      log.Println(message) // example.com
})
```

This is simple wrapper over golang ssh library that helps to execute consequent commands over `/bin/sh`.